# How to use braking in this DC motor control system?

Tags: motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor, braking

I am running a DC motor through a DC controller(DC60DP500-800BL-R01 Keya PWM Electric Vehicle Controller) in a lifter. It's working fine but the only problem is even after stopping the motor the lifter still keeps on moving because of its momentum. I want to make it stop instantly by applying some kind of motor braking. So how can I achieve this? Any suggestion/hint will be greatly appreciated. The circuit is attached. Please have a look and suggest accordingly. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.jnky.com/data/upload/file/20181023/1540257148305708.pdf) of this controller is mostly in Chinese but as much as I can get it has no braking capability. You need another controller.

For comparison, [here](http://www.dcmotorkeya.com/24V-50A-4Q-Braking-Reversible,-PWM-series-DC-Motor-Controller-DC24RT50BL-6-19-1.html) is another controller from the same manufacturer, KEYA Electron. It is not difficult at all to locate and recognize the braking circuit.

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be about how to use a product rather than electrical engineering theory or design. The product appears to be intended for use with a brushed DC motor. A brushed DC motor can be braked by first removing the armature voltage and then connecting a resistor across the motor armature. The resistor must be selected to be suitable for the motor voltage and current rating and the kinetic energy to be absorbed from the load. A suitable controller (not this one) can control the use of the braking resistor. With this controller, you must design an external brake application system.